# Additional submit event handler for webform in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

Im using Drupal 6.19 and the webform module on my site.On a particular form,i want to do some additional processing with the values entered,so i created a module and implemented hook_form_alter, and added my own function called mymodule_webform_submit to the list of submit event handlers.

Suppose i have two fields in the form having field key values name and address respectively. How to print the values of those fields in mymodule_webform_submit function ?. Some example would be really appreciated. Below is my code so far.

```
<?php
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_8') {

         $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_webform_submit';

      }

    }

    function mymodule_webform_submit(&$form,&$form_state) {
      drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['name']);

    }


?>
```

Please help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the arguments to your submit function.  Once those are added, your values should be in $form_state['values'].  It should be something like:

```
function mymodule_webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  print $form_state['values']['name'];
  print $form_state['values']['address'];
}
```

But do whatever you want with the values in there.  Just make sure you have the correct element keys.  You could see what's available by putting var_export($form_state['values']); exit(); inside the function and submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jon.I printed the value of a text field using drupal_set_message,but it does not show anything.Also,tried doing a print as you suggested,but its not printing the value entered by the user before submitting the form.I have edited my code above to reflect the changes made.Please help.

Comment: You could try using "var_export($form_state['values']); exit;" inside the submit function to print everything that the form submitted.  This should show you the structure and what is available.